# Intercepting typos/misstyped symbols and automatically correcting them in the FrontEnd

Tags: front-end, formatting, symbols, meta-programming

I often mistype `Print[]` as PRint[] and `Remove[]` as REmove[]. I was wondering if its possible to use $NewSymbol to intercept these particular typos and literally edit the cell they were made in so I don't even noticed I made the typo. Is this possible?

I know there are other probably easier/safer ways to achieve similar ends. like defining Print[] to point to Print[], but why do that when I could spend forever fixing a minor quality of life issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the function in $NewSymbol does not alter the input, therefore it can only give a warning.

But an easy and simpler solution is to define PRint[] and PRint[] to evaluate to the correct input:

```
PRint[x__] := Print[x];
REmove[x_] := Remove[x];
```

Now you may write e.g:

```
PRint[Hello]

Hello
```